# Android Studio: Load a File into an Array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made a class that can save an array to file, yet, I need it to load the file back into an array inside of an Activity named SampleGridViewAdapter.

Text file format named gallerydump_img.txt:

```
https://mywebsite.com/path/samplefile.rtf
https://anotherwebsite.com/
https://thirdwebsite.com/example/
```

I have tried `strings = LIST[i]`, with `strings` being the output from the file, `i` being the loop, and `LIST` being the array to output the file data to, line by line. More code below:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {

        for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            Log.e("GalleryFileDump", strings[i]);
            ArrayToFile.writeArrayToFile(strings, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/gallerydump_img.txt", "Eww, errors. Want a cookie? :: Unable to write to file gallerydump.bin. Check the report below for more information. :)");
            strings = LIST[i]
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what you have above doesn't compile? That's fine if it doesn't. I just want to be sure I understand the question.

Anyways, one way to serialize and deserialize strings to a file are as follows:

```
String[] readFile(String filename)
{
    String[] strings;

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(filename)));

        String str = reader.readLine();
        while( null != str )
        {
            strings.add(str);
            str = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if( null != reader )
    {
        reader.close();
    }
    return strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
}


void writeFile(String filename, String[] strings )
{
    PrintWriter writer = null;

    try
    {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename)));

        for( int idx = 0; idx < strings.length; idx++ )
        {
            writer.println(strings[idx]);
        }
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if( null != writer )
    {
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: My question is that my `strings = LIST[i]` isn't adding `strings` to the `LIST`'s `i` slot. When I try, it doesn't change `LIST` at all. Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: Is LIST an String[]? If so, you could do LIST[i] = strings[i];. Or if List is a String[][], you could do LIST[i] = strings;

Comment: Sorry, the other link doesn't work. Here is the new one (http://pastebin.com/pwAy5L7F)

Comment: How do you declare/initialize LIST? It looks like it's an array of length 0

Comment: I used `static public String[] LIST = {};`.

Comment: That'll do it. The array is of size 0. If you instead do LIST = strings; in place of the for loop, then LIST will be the output of the file.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! have been stuck on this problem for about a month and finally thought to post. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with everything

Answer (score 1):

This is what you'd want to **read**

```
public static List<String> readLines() {
    File f = new File("gallerydump_img.txt");
    BufferedReader r;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            if ((line = r.readLine()) == null)
                break;
            lines.add(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // file not found
    }
    return lines;
}
```

And this is what you'd want to **write**

```
public static void writeLines(List<String> lines) {
    File f = new File("gallerydump_img.txt");
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        for (String line : lines)
            pw.println(line);
        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // file not found
    }
}
```